# SWT MouseListener MouseEvent interaction

Tags: java, swt

I added a MouseListener with the mouseDown and the mouseDoubleClick event. My Problem is that when i Doubleclick the Mousedown event triggers along with the mouseDoubleClick event. Is there any way to prevent that?

snippet:

```
gamecomp.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
        {
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if(randv==2)
                {
                    score++;
                    scorecount(scorelabel);
                }
                
                else
                {
                    lifeloss++;
                    lifes(lifelabel);
                }
            }
            
            public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e)
            {}
            
            public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if(randv==0)
                {
                    score++;
                    scorecount(scorelabel);
                }
                
                else
                {
                    lifeloss++;
                    lifes(lifelabel);
                }
            }

        });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you could prevent that. But what I think you could do is, add a threaded short timer in the `mouseDown`, add a flag to your `mouseDoubleClick` and check for that flag after the timer ended. So you can decide in your `mouseDown` whether the double click happened or not.

Comment: There is an example [here](https://coderanch.com/t/508053/java/SWT-differ-single-double-click) of using a timer for this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this don't seem to work. I just leave the doubleClick it's not that nessecary.